# If Keras steps_per_epoch argument is set to value less than (num. samples / batch size) will samples used in every epoch be always the same?

Tags: python, keras

I would like to know if setting Keras model.fit **steps_per_epoch** argument to a fixed value that is less than (number of samples in dataset / batch size) will always use the same samples in the dataset (from sample 0 to sample [(steps_per_epoch*batch_size)-1]), reducing so the effective size of the training set, or does it takes steps_per_epoch random samples from the training set(without replacement) of size batch_size in every epoch?

Rgds.

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily try to see the elements inside each of your batches during training by adding a `print()` line inside a custom batch generator. You'll see that your batches are randomly permuted between each epochs (but the samples inside each of them will not if `shuffle` is set to `False`).

Consider for example a dataset of 10 samples, where each of them can be identified by a unique number. If, let's say, `batch_size = 2`, `shuffle = False` and `steps_per_epoch = 10//2 = 5`, then during the first epoch the batches will be called in order (`batch_1 = [1,2]`, `batch_2 = [3,4]`, ..., `batch_5 = [9,10]`). But after this epoch, the batches will be randomly permuted : we'll have for example for the second epoch `batch_4 = [7,8]`, then `batch_1`, `batch_3` etc... and so on until the end of training.

Thus, even if the `steps_per_epoch` argument is less than the recommanded `size_of_dataset // batch_size`, we can deduce that **the batches will still be randomly permuted, implying that your model will still see the entirety of your dataset during training**. Note that this question is trivial is `shuffle = True`, as the elements inside the batches will be randomly  generated at each epoch from the entire dataset.

---

Lastly, I just wanted to share [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/47416) to you, that depicts an interesting use of a reduced `steps_per_epoch`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, just what I needed to clarify the issue